# CICD in tfs 2013

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I am getting an error while creating a Continues integration with TFS -database project. please find the attached screenshot and help me to move forward with my plan.

and also getting doubts on the below things

1. How to set the working directory in build service,
2. What to give the Source control folder and build agent folder.
3. MS Build arguments.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4cPi.jpg)

Comment: Your question does not contain screenshot

Comment: now i have added the screenshot please check

Answer (score 0):

In TFS 2013, build system uses the MSBuild to build the solution/project on the build agent machine. The error in the screenshot means the [SQL Server Data Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/previous-releases-of-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-and-ssdt-bi?view=sql-server-ver15) need to be installed on the **build agent machine**.

Comment: Thanks for the replay and I have some doubts about the same. I have created 1 build controller and 1 build agent in the TFS machine is that correct structure? are you saying to install the SQL Server Data Tools in the TFS machine?

Comment: This topology might work for a team that runs builds infrequently and only during off-hours, such as a team that runs only a single nightly build. You can check the link below to understand build service well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/dd793166%28v%3dvs.120%29#build-system-for-trial-usage-or-a-very-small-team. Also, you need to install the SQL Server Data Tools on the machine where the build agent runs. In your case, the build agent in the TFS machine, then yes, you need to install SQL Server Data Tools in the TFS machine.

Comment: Have you installed SSDT on your build agent machine? Is your issue solved?

Comment: Hi, thank you. I have informed my infra team to install the SSDT and will reply to you soon.

Comment: How's the result?

Comment: Hi, i got the setup file of SQL server 2012. but one more doubt i have, im using sql 2012 server there. then can i get the SSDT from the above mentioned setup file?

Comment: I have SQL server 2012 and I am using visual studio 2015 for taking the build, so which version of ssdt I want to install in TFS machine

Comment: The SSDT version should match the VS version.

Comment: Getting error--- Unable to create the workspace '7_3_ABCD-HQ-SVR1' due to a mapping conflict. You may need to manually delete an old workspace. You can get a list of workspaces on a computer with the command 'tf workspaces /computer:%COMPUTERNAME%'. 
Details: The path C:\Builds\3\DatabaseCICD\BusinessCoreDevDB\src is already mapped in workspace 5_3_ABCD-HQ-SVR1. (type MappingConflictException)

Comment: Have you deleted the old workspace as the error indicated?

Comment: yes but it's not resolved, I have one doubt about the build machine.. actually, I have created 1 build controller and build agent in TFS machine, and I'm building the project from my local machine after creating build definition, is it correct?

Comment: I'm a little confused about your situation. Do you use TFS build or local build? Do you set up build agent on your local machine?

Comment: I have a TFS machine and i have created the build controller and agent there, installed the SSDT 14.0 there, and i am using visual studio 2015 in my local busy and connected to the tfs, after that build definition added from my pc,then buildind from my pc, at that time i got this error